# Button click causes not post back in IE browser asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, postback, page-lifecycle

Its very strange behavior that I'm facing. I have delete button, OnClick  I'm attaching it to that particular event. I'm storing my entire data in Session so, in if(!IsPostBack) i am clearing out the session when the page Initially loads. When i click on the delete button instead of doing IsPostBack = true it does IsPostBack = false in IE and resets the Session data. But, with other browser i do get the expected functionality.
Does any one have any clue about this issue ?

Button tag aspx file,

```
<tr id="rowPurpose">
<td>
    <asp:Label ID="lblPurpose1" Font-Bold="true" runat="server">Purpose</asp:Label>
</td>
<td width="65">
    <asp:Button ID="btnDeletePurpose1"   Text="Delete" Visible="false" CommandArgument="lblPurpose1" OnClick="Delete_Purpose" runat="server" />
</td>
</tr>
```

C# file:

```
void page_load()
{
    rowPurpose.Attributes["onclick"] = "javascript:Method('id')";
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        Session["Key"] = null;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is delete button in a gridview? delete,update,insert is reserved word for gridview. maybe problem occured for that reason?

Comment: no, its not in gridview its just table structure

Comment: If your button is invisible then how are you clicking this button?

Comment: i am making it visible on some condition and that time it is allowed to click according to logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this resolved. From my understanding it was happening because of the two events that are firing at the same time one for the Row and other for the Button click. So i just made cell as clickable instead of whole row and this works fine.

Thanks

Comment: If this is the answer you should mark it as accepter to so it does not list as unanswered  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an HTML submit button or an `<asp:Button>`.  If you are not using the `asp:Button` then it will not perform a post back since the asp version wires up the `PostBack` functionality.  Also make sure you have the `runat="server"` attribute on the button and form.

Can you post your button and form tag in your ASPX page?

Comment: i am using asp button not exatcly sure of this as it works fine with other browser. I am posting my button tag